# How to get nested data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

## Logic

1. Category has Products
2. Products has `brand(1)`, `options(0 or many)`, `tags(0 or many)`, `rating(0 or many)`
3. I want get every `brand`, `options`, `tags`, `ratings` under current category in arrays

> Note: returned data are category based not database based, so each category return different set of data based on what has been provided to that category products.

## Code

`Controller`

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $category = Category::where('active', 'yes')->where('slug', $slug)->with('products')->first();
    return response()->json([
        'data' => new CategoriesFrontResource($category),
        'success'=>'Category retrieved successfully'
    ], 200);
}
```

`Category model`

```
public function products(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'category_products', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

`Product model`

```
public function categories(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_products', 'product_id', 'category_id');
}

public function options(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Option::class, 'option_products', 'product_id', 'option_id');
}

public function tags(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'product_tags', 'product_id', 'tag_id');
}

public function brand(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}

public function rating(){
  return $this->morphMany(Rating::class, 'rateable');
}
```

**Any idea how to achieve that goal?**

## Update

Based on `Jeemusu` answer here is what I have currently

```
$category = Category::where('active', 'yes')->where('slug', $slug)->with(['products', 'products.options', 'products.variations', 'products.brand', 'products.tags', 'products.rating'])->first();
$products = $category->products;
$tags = $products->tags->toArray();
```

And this is the results

```
Property [tags] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Comment: The tags object is nested within each product, you need to loop through them to access it for each product.

Comment: @Jeemusu that I understand, what I'm looking for is a cleaner way such as `map` or `whereHas` etc. so I don't have to make lots of foreach's to get every array I need

Comment: Whats stopping you from using map? `$products->map(function ($product) { return ... });`

Comment: @Jeemusu not being sure what I should write as function

Comment: Probably something like `$products->map(function ($product) { return $products->tags->pluck('title') });` This will get you the title of every tag for every product retrieved in your original query. You can replace title with whatever data your trying to get, or turn it into a collection if it needs further processing.

Comment: If your still struggling, I would create a new question, as this currently goes outside the scope of your original question.

Comment: @Jeemusu `refer to your foreach` solution check this [screenshot](https://ibb.co/rFdMFTs) and about your `map` solution it returns 1 array for each product and not 1 array for all products. `referring to new question` it is my scope (logic #3) get product data in separate arrays.

Comment: You will have to do two nested loops to get the data you want. Create a tags array to append the data to, then merge it in the loop to avoid duplicates. `$tags = []; foreach($products as $product){ foreach($product->tags as $tag) { // merge tag data you want with the tags array } } `

Comment: @Jeemusu thanks man, fixed it already (shared the solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

Following code fixed my issue of getting arrays of each data, but it still needs small fix to return unique data which I created [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62947795/how-to-return-unique-values-in-laravel) for that.

```
    $data = [];
    foreach($products as $i => $product) {
        $data[$i]['brand'] = $product->brand;
        $data[$i]['rating'] = $product->rating;
        $data[$i]['variations'] = $product->variations;
        $data[$i]['options'] = $product->options;
        $data[$i]['tags'] = $product->tags;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you used eager loading to retrieve products related to the category, you can also use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load those products relations.

To quote the documentation:

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax. For example, let's eager load all of the book's authors and all of the author's personal contacts in one Eloquent statement:

For your particular query you can do the following:

```
$category = Category::where('active', 'yes')
    ->where('slug', $slug)
    ->with(
        'products.brand', 
        'products.options', 
        'products.tags', 
        'products.ratings'
    )->first();
```

You can then access the data as you would any object returned from a query:

```
@foreach($category->products as $product
    <h1>{{ $product->brand->title }}</h1>
    @foreach($product->tags as $tag)
        <span>{{ $tag->title }}</span>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: yes that gives me products relations but how to I get those relations in arrays? let say collect all `tags` from all products in this category under tags array. (logic #3)

Comment: I added an example of how you can use the data in your templates.